# Intent to MainActivity starts current Activity again

Tags: android, android-intent

Alright the title is a bit weird. My app starts up on `SplashScreenActivity` which is displayed for 3 seconds and which launches `SignInActivity` to allow the user to login. Clicking a `nextButton` on the `SignInActivity` launches the `MainActivity`.

The issue is that after startup when I click the `nextButton` it relaunches the `SignInActivity` and clicking the `nextButton` a second time takes me to the `MainActivity` which is completely strange. If I launch the `SignInActivity` using any other method and click the `nextButton` it takes me directly to the `MainActivity` without any issues. I've been through my code top and bottom and have no idea what could be causing this issue.

Here's the relevant code

```
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true).apply();
                Log.d("TAG", "Logged in Shared Preferences Set");
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false).apply();
                Log.d("TAG", "Not Logged in Shared Preferences Set");
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Sign In was Skipped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Interestingly I commented out the `startActivity()` method to see if it relaunched the activity but it did not.
What's wrong here?

Update : Lifecycle Log -> No idea why `SignInActivity` isn't destroyed in the first case and what causes the activity to be recreated.

(Not logged in via either facebook or google+)

```
10-27 00:46:20.549 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:46:21.464 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: handleSignInResult:false
10-27 00:46:29.593 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Not Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:46:29.692 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: MainActivity Created
10-27 00:46:30.049 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:46:30.211 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: handleSignInResult:false
10-27 00:46:30.473 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
10-27 00:46:48.274 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Not Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:46:48.674 22392-22392/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
```

(Logged in via facebook cached login)

```
10-27 00:51:17.411 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:51:20.378 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:51:20.438 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: MainActivity Created
10-27 00:51:20.701 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:51:21.100 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
10-27 00:51:26.960 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:51:27.326 28298-28298/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
```

(Logged in via Google+ cached login)

```
10-27 00:53:29.039 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:53:33.133 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: handleSignInResult:true
10-27 00:53:44.096 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:53:44.204 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: MainActivity Created
10-27 00:53:44.565 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:53:44.954 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
10-27 00:53:45.358 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: handleSignInResult:true
10-27 00:53:52.674 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:53:53.120 30454-30454/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
```

I created a new Blank Activity and replaced the `MainActivity` with `BlankActivity` within the `nextButton` click method and everything was fine. Here's the Lifecycle log :

```
10-27 00:56:19.538 1502-1502/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Created
10-27 00:56:22.116 1502-1502/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: handleSignInResult:false
10-27 00:56:24.747 1502-1502/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: Not Logged in Shared Preferences Set
10-27 00:56:24.849 1502-1502/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: BlankActivity Created
10-27 00:56:25.244 1502-1502/com.dhyanfoundation.vedicchants D/Log: SignInActivity Destroyed
```

Comment: Can you post the code for SplashScreen ?

Comment: where did you initialize isLoggedIn ?

Comment: Add some logging to the lifecycle methods in each `Activity`. That might give you a better understanding of what is going on. I don't see how the `SignInActivity` can launch the `SignInActivity` based on the code you posted.

Comment: Try putting that toast message before you call startActivity with your intent.

Comment: Updated with Lifecycle log. isLoggedIn is initialized in onCreate. Changing the position of Toast made no difference. The SplashScreen activity just contains a runnable with an intent to start `SignInActivity` nothing else there

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: Sorry for answering this so late, there was an issue with the code. Another developer was trying his hands on something through my PC and had added code in another activity that launched the SplashScreenActivity again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should have a re-look at your design. When the user tries to log in through the app, the logic to check his login status should be done in the intent redirection from *SplashScreenActivity* itself.

Assuming you have tracked the log in status correctly, you activity flow should be like this:

1) *SplashScreenActivity*->*MainActivity* (if user is logged in)

2) *SplashScreenActivity*->*SignInActivity*->*MainActivity* (if user is not logged in)

If the user login status is false, he should be redirected to *SignInActivity* and there in the onclick event of nextButton, his credentials should be verified and then login status should be updated and then he should be redirected to *MainActivity*.

Within your *MainActivity* you should allow the user to log out and there, the login status should be updated to false.

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but many a times such bugs can be eliminated by rethinking the design and making it robust in that level itself.